# How to find pattern in String and remove everything which doesn't match

Tags: java, android, regex

How i can remove everything from the String line and get information what was match to pattern?

for example i have some Strings as input:

1. "blabbl myexample@ex.com"
   i want get only email
   or
2. "company blbalbal phone: 88 99 99 247 fax: 99 88 14 574"
   i want get only phone number

I'm using Pattern to check if String contain email or number but I don't know how i can remove all other Strings from that and get only what was matched

Some suggestions or example ?

```
int start,end,length;
String text ="bleble blabbl myexample@ex.com blabla"
Pattern emailP = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.com");
Matcher matcherEmail =emailP.matcher(text);
if (matcherEmail.find()) {
start=matcherEmail.start();


//substring
tekst=tekst.substring(0,start);
Matcher matcherEmail =emailP.matcher(text);
end=matcherEmail.end();
length=text.length();
tekst=text.substring(end,length);
}
```

so, it will be something like that?
to remove everything before matched pattern and after 
i need check String 2 times?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and why it didn't work. Also, a Minimal, Compilable and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Instead of removing, you could also match instead https://ideone.com/FQsmm8

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `.+@.+\.com` matches any char 1+ times including spaces, an `@` and again 1+ chars including spaces. Note that the `.+` is greedy and will match until the end of the string and will match [more than](https://regex101.com/r/aILIoL/1) just an email address.

One possibility instead of removing what is not an email address is to match and use `\S` instead of `.+` which matches a non-whitespace character:

```
\S+@\S+\.com\b
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\S+@\\S+\\.com\\b";
String text ="bleble blabbl myexample@ex.com blabla";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/606fHZ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FQsmm8)

To get the phone number you could use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/5HomWD/1) with a  [capturing group](https://ideone.com/CUxZTf).